# Symfony admin generator generated module has no style

Tags: symfony1

I am using Symfony 1.31 for a brand new project. I have just created a module in the backend app, using the admin generator. To my suprise, it seems no theme ((At all) has been applied to the pages. As I mentioned before, this si abrand new project - I have not even modified the /app/backend/layout.php file yet.

I rember having a similar problem before - I dont remmber how I solved it (I think I had to run a task or copy some files over to the /web folder before the styles/images etc came into efect. Can anyone refresh my memory?

Comment: Check with e.g. Firebug whether all files (e.g. CSS, JS) get downloaded or not.

Comment: totally un-related, but best to use 1.4 for new projects if possible, as its the long term service release and should be a bit faster as some of the legacy/deprecated features have been removed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might need to run the `plugin:publish-assets` command:

```
php symfony plugin:publish-assets
```

This will create symlinks to your plugins' `web/` directory inside your project's `web/`, thus enabling access to sfDoctrinePlugin's (or propel depending what ORM you use) admin-gen styles.

Comment: Thanks - thats what it was. I forgot to publish-assets. Ok, I'm off to stand in the corner, with my face to the wall now, ... :p

Answer (score 1):

Check your apache configuration and files permissions, and especially the alias to the /sf/ subdirectory. It seems that the .css file corresponding to sf_admin pages are not accessible. You can fix it by adding an Alias to your virtualhost configuration, or allowing symlinks.

(By the way, hint: check your html source, find out the .css url, and try to access it directly with your browser)